# Namedtuple vs Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, types, namedtuple, python-3.6

So I'm programming a game and I need a datatype that can store a multitude of variables ranging from `lists`, `tuples`, `strings` and `integers`. I'm torn between using either `dictionaries` or `namedtuples`.

```
GameData = namedtuple('GameData', ['Stats', 'Inventory', 'Name', 'Health'])
current_game = GameData((20,10,55,3), ['Sword', 'Apple', 'Potion'], 'Arthur', 100)

GameData = {'Stats': (20,10,55,3), 'Inventory': ['Sword', 'Apple', 'Potion'], 'Name': 'Arthur', 'Health': 100}
```

You see, the biggest problem here is all of these values may change, so I need a mutable datatype, which is not the `namedtuple`. Looking in the docs, `namedtuples` appear to have `._replace()`, so does that make it mutable?

I also like how `namedtuples` have a `__repr__` method that prints in the `name=value` format. Also, the functionality of assigning separate `__doc__` fields to each value in the `namedtuple` is very useful. Is there this functionality with `dictionaries`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use a `class`. 
The problem with dictionaries is that you don't know which keys to expect and your IDE won't be able to autocomplete for you. 
The problem with namedtuple is that is not mutable. 
With a custom class you get both readable attributes, mutable objects and a lot of flexibility. Some alternatives to consider:

- Starting from Python 3.7 you could use the `dataclasses` module:

  ```
  from dataclasses import dataclass

  @dataclass
  class GameData:
      stats: tuple
      inventory: list
      name: str
      health: int
  ```
- In case other Python versions, you could try [attrs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrs/) package:

  ```
  import attr

  @attr.s
  class GameData:
      stats = attr.ib()
      inventory = attr.ib()
      name = attr.ib()
      health = attr.ib()
  ```

Comment: Also, what do you mean by _The problem with dictionaries is that you don't know which keys to expect_ ?

Comment: I mean that with the dictionary you don't declare the structure. Sure you create it somewhere but it can mutate in another place of your code.

Comment: VS Code is capable of suggesting the keys for a dictionary

Answer (score 3):

> Looking in the docs, `namedtuples` appear to have `._replace()`, so does that make it mutable?

**No**, as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace), it creates a new `namedtuple`, with the value replaced.

If you want the data to be mutable, you better construct a class yourself.